# Creating a link to open a page that corresponds with that link

Tags: javascript, php, html, hyperlink, pagination

I'm trying to create a pagination (say I used this example: http://allitstuff.com/php-mysql-pagination-script-download/) with links that will open up to display a record from the database.

For example (MySQL database):

```
ID | Product Name | Price | Pictures
____________________________________
1  | Shoes        | £30   | image
2  | Jeans        | £15   | image
```

With pagination it'll output both those records above, and previous and next button.

How do I convert those two records into separate clickable links that when clicked on it'll set the value into a pre-made page.

The pre-made page will get and display upon clicking the link that corresponds with it.

Like a eBay list, when I click on link 1, it'll direct me to a page with everything about link 1, and link 1 only.

I understand how to retrieve and set records (storing as variables) with a simple echo. But I do not know how to make a link that directs the user to a page which matches what he/she clicked on.

Perhaps if I click on the link then it'll post the ID, and on the displaying page, if ID is equal to the post ID then display its content?

**But my main question is how to convert records to links that corresponds with itself.**

Comment: Sounds like you need some sort of system in place to handle unique product URLs. Using the product ID is the best bet. So that you can link to and have a page with url similar to `/product.php?id=1` for those Shoes.

Answer (score 0):

You basically have to make a list of al the products in your database and use a get variable in your URL.

```
<a href="yourstore.tld?product=<?php //Get productid here ?>"><?php //Get productname here ?></a>
```

This way you get links that point to:
yourstore.tld?product=1
yourstore.tld?product=2
...

If you make a product.php page than you use 
`$_GET['product']` to build a sql query to get the rest of the info.

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = $_GET['product']
```

Comment: I see. That makes sense. Can you explain to me what does the ? do in tld?product  ? Also, when generating records, I should wrap the record around with the link tags (the first line of code you've mentioned) and it'll create links of that record?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Maybe not the best resource for this but the first I found:
http://html.net/tutorials/php/lesson10.php

Comment: Thanks, that clears up my confusion on URL syntax. I'll create a PHP page with a list of records from products, and will test out the hyperlink with passed record variable as you suggested. I'll get back to you once I've finished implementing the pagination with converted clickable links. Martyn.